# mail not sending to @gmail and @hotmail, but sending to @mydomain

Tags: php, email

I tried to send email using php mail() function. It is sending to @mydomain email id,but it is not sending to @gmail and @hotmail. It shows the message "failed" (see the code below)

```
<?php


if($_POST['name'])
{
    $subject = "Message from website";

    $name = $_POST['name'];
    $email = $_POST['email'];
    $number = $_POST['number'];
    $to = 'xxx@gmail.com';

    $txt = " Name : " . $name . " \r\n Email : " . $email . " \r\n Contact No. : " . $number;

    $mail = mail($to, $subject, $txt, "From: ".$name." <".$email.">\r\n"."Reply-To: ".$email."\r\n"."X-Mailer: PHP/" . phpversion());

    if($mail)
    {
        echo "Thank You!";

    }

    if(!$mail)
    {
        echo "failed";//print_r(error_get_last());
    }
}
else
    echo "no values entered";
?>
```

When I send it to @gmail or hotmail address it shows the message "failed".

If I add print_r(error_get_last()) instead of 'echo "failed"', it shows blank

I googled for answers,but no luck. Many answers related are years old. I hope someone help me.

Thanks in advance

Comment: can you post the error response also in your question ?

Comment: Have you enabled the less secure apps in Google mail? http://www.google.com/settings/security/lesssecureapps

Comment: You also need to specify the smtp protocol and the use of ssl

Comment: Your `$to` address doesn't change it is always emailing to `@gmail.com`. The `From` header changes, maybe it is going to your spam in gmail?

Comment: I am new in php, so I dont know how to get error response. It shows "failed"

Comment: This will help you with the setup http://stackoverflow.com/q/712392/3631728

Comment: Thank you all for your valueable replies. Calle, how to specify smtp and ssl. I am using mail() function